# Python: gracefully catching core dumps

Tags: python, exception, coredump

I've got (multiple) functions which I need to call a large number of times with essentially random arguments, and I need to create a log of what is returned each time, and with what arguments. Usually the function returns something or raises an error, in which case I can handle it fine.

However, I've now found some arguments that cause the function to cause a core dump, which also kills my script. What I would prefer is to raise an exception, which could then get handled by my existing exception handling code. Then it would get recorded as normal, and continue testing other inputs. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by coredump? Are you segfaulting the interperter? Anyway, that obviously can't be recovered from within the Python process.

Comment: The error I'm getting is python: `mod.cu:864: void NVMatrix::_aggregate(int, NVMatrix&, Agg, BinaryOp) [with Agg = NVMatrixAggs::Sum, BinaryOp = NVMatrixBinaryOps::SecondScaled, NVMatrix = NVMatrix]: Assertion 'numBlocks < 65535' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`. I'm trying to come up with a way around this with multiprocessing, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: It is a subprocess that python has bindings to that segfaults. See how [gberseth](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gberseth/blog/handling-segfaults-in-python-that-occur-in-custom-c-libraries.html) handles this by registering a _sig_handler_ or integrating the segfault as a python exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950296/using-try-to-avoiding-a-segmentation-fault